# Django project global name 'user' is not defined

Tags: python, django

```
NameError at /friendship/profile/
global name 'user' is not defined

\views.py in profile_view, line 51


def profile_view(request):
    p = Profile.objects.filter(user=user).first()
    u = p.user
    sent_friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=p.user)
    rec_friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(to_user=p.user)

    friends = p.friends.all()
```

I keep getting this error its in the view its a django view it says that the problem is in the u = p.user 
I get this error,   NameError at /friendship/profile/
    global name 'user' is not defined

Answer (score 2):

You can't get that error at the line you quote (`u = p.user`). But you can, and should, get it on the previous line. Replace `.filter(user=user)` with `.filter(user=request.user)`.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to be in this line:

```
p = Profile.objects.filter(user=user).first()
```

Specifically, the `user` you are checking against (to the right of the `=` sign) is a variable that doesn't appear to be defined anywhere.

Without some more context as to what you're trying to do, it's hard to say how to fix it. I would say though that either you mean to check against the user making the request - in which case use `request.user` - or you have some parameters in your URL which you should be getting this value from.